# Changed textures inside blender aren't updating when rendering

Tags: rendering, texturing

When I create a new texture in blender everything works fine, I put it on an object and I'm able to render (shift+z render) it even if I have painted it, the problem comes when I reopen the project, every texture loads correctly and I'm able to paint them, but I have to save the texture for being able to see it when rendering, otherwise it just renders like if I haven't made any change (like if I just was reloading the image)[image: Without rendering]
[image: With rendering]